# Vuejs2 multiple if condition

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

I want to convert my php code into vuejs2 code as I'am changing my adminpanel as vue application(only ui).
I'am following this documentation, https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

This is my art.vue component

```
   <template>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="box box-info">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
          <h3 class="box-title">Latest Artworks</h3>

          <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table no-margin">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>ID</th>
                          <th>Art</th>
                          <th>Artist</th>
                          <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr v-for="item in art">
                            <td>
                                <a href="{{URL::route('arts',['id' => $art->id])}}">ART-{{ $art->.id }}</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
                            <td>{{ item.artist.name }}</td>
                            <td>
                              <span class="label 
                                    <?php 
                                    if(item.status == "Pending")
                                      echo 'label-warning';
                                    elseif($art['status'] == "Approved")
                                      echo 'label-success';
                                    else
                                      echo 'label-danger';
                                    ?>
                                ">{{$art['status']}}</span> </td>
                            <td>
                              <div class="sparkbar" data-color="#00a65a" data-height="20"><canvas width="34" height="20" style="display: inline-block; width: 34px; height: 20px; vertical-align: top;"></canvas></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer clearfix">
            <a href="{{URL::route('arts')}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-flat pull-right">View All</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    computed : {
        latest(){
            return this.$store.state.art.latest
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I have seen v-if condition statement, but in my case i have multiple conditions

I want to change this code

```
<span class="label 
    <?php 
    if($art['status'] == "Pending")
      echo 'label-warning';
    elseif($art['status'] == "Approved")
      echo 'label-success';
    else
      echo 'label-danger';
    ?>
">{{$art['status']}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve multiple conditional views easily using `v-else-if`s. Refer to the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt) here.

**EDIT**: Looking at the code sample it felt that there is no need for `v-if`s. To add classes to an element can be done by the means of property binding.

```
<span class="label 
  <?php 
    if(item.status == "Pending")
      echo 'label-warning';
    elseif($art['status'] == "Approved")
      echo 'label-success';
    else
      echo 'label-danger';
   ?>
">{{$art['status']}}</span>
```

can be written like:

```
<span :class='{label: true, "Pending": item.status === 'value', "label-warning": item.status === 'someOtherValue'}'>{{$art['status']}}</span>
```

in `vuejs` for the same effect, [read more](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax).

Comment: yeah i'have seen this.but how to apply to make visible a class in the html element

Comment: I'll just edit my answer to contain that, and btw you can do that using template tag.

Comment: @GeethuJojo you don't need `v-if` at all for this. You can bind classes. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: sorry, i didn't get you. <span :class='{label: true, "Pending": item.status, label-warning: !item.status}'>item.status</span>

Comment: @GeethuJojo You can test the code out and also refer to the documentation for class binding. `v-if` is to be used when you want to conditionally render `html`. For conditional properties, you can do it with property binding.

Comment: <span :class='{label: true, "Pending": item.status, label-warning: !item.status}'>{{item.status }}</span>  gives me syntax error invalid expression: :class="{label: true, "Pending": item.status, label-warning: !item.status}

Comment: @GeethuJojo Sorry, The last class was not enclosed in double quotes. The classnames must be quote enclosed if they have `-` between the name.

Comment: The value of item.status is not either true or false, but pending,/approved/rejected. I think we can't do like that.

Comment: @GeethuJojo just add that in the condition like in the edit

Comment: <span :class='{label: true, "label-warning": item.status === 'Pending', "label-success": item.status === 'Approved',"label-danger": item.success === 'Rejected'}'>{{item.status}}</span> i tried this one and in the browser i'am getting like this under status field - ', "label-success": item.status == 'Approved',"label-danger": item.success == 'Rejected'}'>Approved. don't know what is wrong with me

Comment: Your single quotes will make the syntax incorrect. Use double quotes throughout. `<span :class='{label: true, "label-warning": item.status === "Pending", "label-success": item.status === "Approved","label-danger": item.success === "Rejected"}'>{{item.status}}</span>` single quotes to enclose the object, double to enclose the strings inside, you can reverse their roles though.

Answer (score -1):

```
<span v-if="item.status === 'Pending'" class="label label-warning">
    {{ item.status }}
</span>
<span v-else-if="item.status === 'Approved'" class="label label-success">
    {{ item.status }}
</span>
<span v-else class="label label-danger">
    {{ item.status }}
</span>
```

This solved my issue